# Google Earth Plugin, embedded in Blogger, producing 2 maps

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin, kmz

Curious problem whilst embedding a Google Earth network link into Blogger.
The code I'm using is as shown below, but I'm getting two instances of GE on the same page, one above the other.
They must be getting generated seperately, as if I stick a border into the divs style on the page it only affects one instance.

```
<div id="map3d" style="border: 4px solid silver; height: 768px; width: 1024px;"></div>
```

However, if I remove this code from the page entirely. both instances vanish.

Other than that I've got it functioning as I'm wanting. (Eventually)

This is the code I've got in the head section

```
<!-- Earth -->
<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi?key=mykey"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var ge;
  google.load("earth", "1", {"other_params":"sensor=false"});

  function init() {
     google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
  }

  function initCB(instance) {
     ge = instance;
     ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
     ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_SHOW);

     var href = 'http://urltomykmz';

     google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, function(kmlObject) {
           if (kmlObject)
              ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
           if (kmlObject.getAbstractView() !== null)
              ge.getView().setAbstractView(kmlObject.getAbstractView());
     });
  }

  function failureCB(errorCode) {
  }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
</script>
<!-- Earth -->
```

Grateful to anyone who can point to what's causing the second instance. Thanks.

Comment: If you inspect the generated HTML which `<div>` code do you get? If you change the `id` the problem persists?

Comment: The 1st instance is the correct one. This picks up the style entered in the page body.

Div info shows as "Width = 1020px Height = 776px
#map3d Width = 1032px Height = 776px
Width = 1024px Height = 768px
Width = 1024px Height = 768px
#_idlglue_pluginDiv___idlglue_plugin__99 Width = 1024px Height = 768px"

The 2nd instance only shows "Width = 1024px Height = 768px
#_idlglue_pluginDiv___idlglue_plugin__99" No #map3d

Comment: What about the second one? Maybe Blogger is changing the markup?

Comment: Sorry I hit return before entering info about the 2nd one. Now edited.

Comment: It's quite hard without a Blogger account to know what's going on. Try to recreate the problem in a public page with the minimum amount of code.

Comment: Exactly what I was doing. :-) http://tinyurl.com/q59t9y3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove either the call to `init()` in your `onload` handler or the call to `google.setOnLoadCallback(init)`, otherwise a map will be added every time you call the `init` function.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Always something simple.